# Unity Greeter starts with a black output Screen

Tags: 14.04, unity, lightdm, login-screen, unity-greeter

The unity greeter in my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop starts with a black output screen. When I say this I mean every error and output of the greeter is printed on the screen but the GUI is not visible.

What I do to make it work for me is:

> 1.Login using my password assuming that my user is selected(looking at the output on the screen)
>   NOTE:Even after logging in nothing is visible except the black screen.
>   2.Press a key combination that I set to restart unity or lightdm (sorry for the confusion).

Only by doing this on every startup am I able to see the GUI

How Can I solve this once and for all.

**Update 1:** It seems that the black screen is a Debug screen as every output is preceded with a `Debug:`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what caused the problem or exactly what was going wrong but I was able to solve the problem by purging and installing lightdm

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm && apt-get install lightdm
```